# Magento 2 - Getting product Image url in Model/block not in template file?

Tags: magento2, product, url, image

I am sending product data as response for the rest  api call, I want to get product Image Url, currently using this:

```
$imagehelper = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
$image = $imagehelper->init($product, 'category_page_list')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(400)->getUrl();
```

but getting following URL :

> http://XXXX.com/pub/static/webapi_rest/_view/en_US/Magento_Catalog/images/product/placeholder/.jpg

Not getting any image .

Thanks.

referring the following Question : [Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84772/magento-2-keep-product-image-aspect-ratio)

Comment: I am sending product data as response for the rest  api call, I want to get product Image Url in our model or block file not in template. So the question is different from the mentioned duplicate question...thanks.

Answer (score 13):

You can get product image url using this code:

```
$productImageUrl = $block->getUrl('pub/media/catalog').'product'.$_product->getImage();
```

Answer (score 5):

Try it

```
$store = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore();
$imageUrl = $store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $product->getImage();
```

Comment: Since I didn't have $objectManager, I defined it as \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(). But the rest of the things worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

you can get product image url using below code:

```
    $imageBlock =  $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct');
//get product object...
    $productImage = $imageBlock->getImage($product, 'category_page_list');
    <a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $productImage->toHtml()  ?></a>
```

you can get product image with product url.
Thanks.