# Magento 2 : Display grouped product pictures in template

Tags: magento2, product-images, grouped-products

I am trying to display the grouped product images on my product page. So I extended the **grouped.phtml** file in my theme and modified it as follow:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * Grouped product data template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\BaseImage
 * @var $block \Magento\GroupedProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Grouped
 */
?>
<?php $block->setPreconfiguredValue(); ?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $_associatedProducts = $block->getAssociatedProducts(); ?>
<?php $_hasAssociatedProducts = count($_associatedProducts) > 0; ?>
<?php $_imagehelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image'); ?>

<div class="table-wrapper grouped">
    <table class="table data grouped" id="super-product-table">
        <caption class="table-caption"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Grouped product items') ?></caption>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col picture" scope="col"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Product Picture') ?></th>
            <th class="col item" scope="col"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Product Name') ?></th>
            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <th class="col qty" scope="col"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?></th>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <?php if ($_hasAssociatedProducts): ?>
            <?php foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_item): ?>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="col picture" scope="col">
                        <?php $productImage = $block->getImage($_item, 'product_thumbnail_image');
                        echo $productImage->toHtml();
                        ?>
                    </td>
                    <td data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Product Name')); ?>" class="col item">
                        <strong class="product-item-name"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></strong>
                        <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)): ?>
                            <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)): ?>
                                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductPrice($_item) ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </td>
                    <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <td data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')); ?>" class="col qty">
                            <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()) : ?>
                                <div class="control qty">
                                    <input type="number" name="super_group[<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getId() ?>]"
                                           data-selector="super_group[<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getId() ?>]"
                                           maxlength="12"
                                           value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getQty() * 1 ?>"
                                           title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>"
                                           class="input-text qty"
                                           data-validate="{'validate-grouped-qty':'#super-product-table'}"
                                           data-errors-message-box="#validation-message-box"/>
                                </div>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <div class="stock unavailable" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Availability') ?>">
                                    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Out of stock') ?></span>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </td>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </tr>
                <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)
                    && $block->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)
                    && trim($block->getProductPriceHtml(
                        $_item,
                        \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice::PRICE_CODE
                    ))): ?>
                    <tr class="row-tier-price">
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <?php echo $block->getProductPriceHtml(
                                $_item,
                                \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice::PRICE_CODE
                            ) ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </tbody>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="unavailable"
                    colspan="<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>4<?php else : ?>3<?php endif; ?>">
                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('No options of this product are available.') ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="validation-message-box"></div>
```

So the first column of my grouped product table is the main picture of the grouped product.

Right now, I get a placeholder:

```
<img class="product-image-photo" src="http://BASEURL/static/frontend/Vendor/theme/en_US/Magento_Catalog/images/product/placeholder/thumbnail.jpg" width="50" height="50" alt="Leurre de manger">
```

But if I change to $_product instaed of $_item I get the parent picture (the main grouped picture) to display...

```
<td class="col picture" scope="col">
                        <?php $productImage = $block->getImage($_product, 'product_thumbnail_image');
                        echo $productImage->toHtml();
                        ?>
</td>
```

How can I display the individual grouped pictures?

Comment: Read more: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/112304/33057

Comment: Same thing, getting this url: [link](Same thing, getting this url: HTTP://BASEURL/STATIC/FRONTEND/VENDOR/THEME/EN_US/MAGENTO_CATALOG/IMAGES/PRODUCT/PLACEHOLDER/IMAGE.JPG)

Comment: Hey, DId you get the solution?

Comment: i tried it using Object manager and worked for me

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 

<img src="<?php echo $block->getUrl('pub/media/catalog').'product'. $simpleproduct->getSmallImage();?>" width="150" height="150" />

Answer (score 0):

You can get item image using below code.

```
<?php $productImage = $block->getImage($_item, 'product_thumbnail_image'); ?>

<img src="<?= $productImage->getImageUrl(); ?>" />
```