# Magento 2 convert GETURL from Magento 1

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have searched in Magento 2 developer documentation and also googled about the new Magento 2 GET URL method but haven't found something clear that explain how to get url path in new platform.

So I open up this post to complete with your help the missing commands and help also other user searching for the same argument.

The Magento 1 Platform

```
GET PRODUCT URL
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product')->getProductUrl($_product); ?>

GET ATTRIBUTE
<?php echo $_product->getData('manufacturer'); ?>
<?php echo $_product->getSku(); ?>

GET PRODUCT NAME
<?php echo $_product->getName(); ?>

GET DESCRIPTION
<?php echo strip_tags($_product->getDescription()); ?>

GET KEYWORDS
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getKeywords()) ?>

GET PRODUCT IMAGE
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(300, 300); ?>
```

The Magento 2 Platform

```
GET BASE URL
This is the only reference I have found
<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl(); ?>
```

if I try all other Magento 1 parameters to get the URL/ATTRIBUTE/NAME etc. Magento 2 crash.

Comment: How about your issue?

Answer (score 0):

**Get product url from Helper**

In your template, we can call directly (however, should be injected in our Block)

```
$this->helper->('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product')->getProductUrl($product);
```

**Get Product attributes in product listing**

*vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml*

```
/**
 * Product list template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
 */

 $_productNameStripped = $block->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true);

$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');

$_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getManufacturer(), 'manufacturer');

$_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name');

$_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getDescription(), 'description')

$productImage = $block->getImage($_product, $image);
echo $productImage->toHtml();
```

**Product Image helper**

[Magento 2 - Keep Product Image Aspect Ratio](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84772/magento-2-keep-product-image-aspect-ratio)

```
//$image = 'category_page_grid' or 'category_page_list';
 $_imagehelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');

 $productImage = $_imagehelper->init($_product, $image)->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(400)->getUrl();
```

**Note:** some Helpers help us to get the product url easily, however, for the best practise, they should be injected in the constructor of our Blocks.